# Unable to create "PRIVATE CONNECTIONS TO SERVICES" to use for Memcached service

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Following the documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-services-access#allocate-ip-address-range

I've been trying to create a private connection to be able create a **Memcached** instance(since I'm getting this error while trying to create a **Memcached** instance)

**Command:**
`gcloud memcache instances create instance-one-memcached --node-count=1 --node-cpu=1 --node-memory=1GB --region=europe-west1 --zones=europe-west1-b --memcached-version=1.5`

**Result:**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.memcache.instances.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Google private service access is not enabled. Enable private service access and try again. For information on enabling private service access, see https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/enabling-private-services-access
com.google.cloud.memcache.action.validator.sn.ServiceNetworkingException: <eye3 title='FAILED_PRECONDITION'/> generic::FAILED_PRECONDITION: Google private service access is not enabled. Enable private service access and try again. For information on enabling private service access, see https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/enabling-private-services-access
```

**Creating a "PRIVATE CONNECTIONS TO SERVICES" fails either from GCP console or when using gcloud command**

**Command:**
`gcloud services vpc-peerings connec --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com --ranges=google-managed-services-one-vpc --network=net-one-vpc -project=proj-one`

**Result:**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.services.vpc-peerings.connect) The operation "operations/pssn.p24-719941109999-d25a7fa1-412f-4fd5-ace8-75acf6c9943f" resulted in a failure "Cannot modify allocated ranges in CreateConnection. Please use UpdateConnection.
Help Token: AZ-7fWLZ_U_RQbchXmaYK0WCFVFtlYHYW72o0aEMipuTjzE9kD1ja82MELMMRv-bMvoEjYIdJTHJMIpDm16uv437QhqtOSdNZeXMTkBaMxIK2N5t".
Details: "[<DetailsValueListEntry
 additionalProperties: [<AdditionalProperty
 key: '@type'
 value: <JsonValue
 string_value: 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure'>>, <AdditionalProperty
 key: 'violations'
 value: <JsonValue
 array_value: <JsonArray
 entries: [<JsonValue
 object_value: <JsonObject
 properties: [<Property
 key: 'type'
 value: <JsonValue
 string_value: 'googleapis.com'>>, <Property
 key: 'subject'
 value: <JsonValue
 string_value: '171070'>>]>>]>>>]>, <DetailsValueListEntry
 additionalProperties: [<AdditionalProperty
 key: '@type'
 value: <JsonValue
 string_value: 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo'>>, <AdditionalProperty
 key: 'reason'
 value: <JsonValue
 string_value: 'FLOW_SN_PF_UPDATE_PEERING_MODIFY_RANGE_IN_CREATE'>>, <AdditionalProperty
 key: 'domain'
 value: <JsonValue
 string_value: 'servicenetworking.googleapis.com'>>]>]".
```

**I have two subnets with the ranges:**

```
sub-one-private-subnet  europe-west1             net-one-vpc  10.4.0.0/16    IPV4_ONLY
sub-one-public-subnet   europe-west1             net-one-vpc  10.2.0.0/16    IPV4_ONLY
```

**I have one "PRIVATE CONNECTIONS TO SERVICES":**

```
Connection name | Assigned allocation | Service producer
servicenetworking-googleapis-com | sub-one-db-subnet | Google Cloud Platform
```

*I'm using the range -one-db-subnet 10.3.0.0/24*

**And have two "ALLOCATED IP RANGES FOR SERVICES":**

```
services-one-subnet    =>    10.5.0.0/16
google-managed-services-one-vpc    =>    10.89.0.0/16
```

How to create a "PRIVATE CONNECTIONS TO SERVICES", is it a problem from my end? or the docs are missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I tried replicating this concern and I successfully create a memcached using this [link](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/memcached/create-manage-instances) what Ive done is that under creating memcached, I chose the custom vpc I created. I also set up the connection of private service access and selec “Use an automatically allocated IP Range” then click continue. After a few minutes it will show an established connection. Below are the screenshots of my replication.

I also use your subnet to make sure it is not a IP address issue.

[image][image][image]